# Mysql Flatten an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, flatten

The table contains json data and i wanted to extract labelKey from this json

table: **d_json**

| data |
| --- |
| {"tag":null,"options":[{"labelKey":"key10","value":"yes","selected":true},{"labelKey":"key11","value":"no","selected":false}]} |
| {"tag":null,"options":[{"labelKey":"key20","value":"yes","selected":true},{"labelKey":"key21","value":"no","selected":false},{"labelKey":"key22","value":"no","selected":false}]} |

I used following query to extract "labelKey"

> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(j.data,'$.options'),'$[*].labelKey') FROM d_json j AS result;

It returns following result

| result |
| --- |
| ["key10", "key12"] |
| ["key20", "key21", "key22"] |

However i want result in flat, each row contains one element instead of array, such as

| result |
| --- |
| "key10" |
| "key11" |
| "key21" |
| "key22" |
| "key23" |

Not getting any clue how to flatten resulted arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mysql v8+, you can do that using [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM d_json, 
     JSON_TABLE(data, '$.options[*]' COLUMNS (
                labelKey VARCHAR(40) PATH '$.labelKey')
     ) p;
```

Result:

| labelKey |
| --- |
| key10 |
| key11 |
| key20 |
| key21 |
| key22 |

Here's a [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57152591f65380f445cbe22d439dc95c)

**Edit:**

On older MySQL version, try this:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val2,',',rn),',',-1))
FROM (SELECT 1 rn UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) AS r
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(val),'[',''),']','') AS val2
     FROM 
       (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(j.data,'$.options'),'$[*].labelKey') AS val
      FROM d_json j) v1 
    ) v2;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=503850f2037330359b8f37b15dac035a)

The idea is to `CROSS JOIN` with a sequence of row numbers then use that same sequence to extract from a `GROUP_CONCAT` values using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. In the query example above, I'm using a hardcoded row sequences in the form of:

```
(SELECT 1 rn UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) AS r
```

Ideally, the best approach is to figure out the sequence required and generate it dynamically.

**Update:**

Generating numbering sequences on older MySQL version is a challenge especially if we're aiming for a dynamic generating. There's a method that is not dynamic but can generate a large numbering sequence from a very long query but if you're planning to be using this sequences for a long time, I suggest you just create a table for it:

```
CREATE TABLE number_seq (
sequences INT);

INSERT INTO number_seq
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS rn FROM 
(SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION 
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1 CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION 
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2 CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION 
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3 CROSS JOIN
(SELECT @row:=0) numbers;
```

The query above will generate a range of numbers from 1-1000 and insert into a table. Once you have that table, you just need to write your query like this:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val2,',',sequences),',',-1))
FROM (SELECT sequences FROM 
(SELECT (LENGTH(val2)-LENGTH(REPLACE(val2,',','')))+1 AS valLen FROM
(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(val),'[',''),']','') AS val2 FROM 
       (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(j.data,'$.options'),'$[*].labelKey') AS val
      FROM d_json j) v1 
    ) v2 ) v3 JOIN number_seq t ON sequences <= valLen) r
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(val),'[',''),']','') AS val2
     FROM 
       (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(j.data,'$.options'),'$[*].labelKey') AS val
      FROM d_json j) v1 
    ) v2;
```

The highlight of change from the previous query is the switch between the hardcoded numbering sequences with a query that basically get the total values separated by comma in the final `JSON_EXTRACT` and join it against the created `number_seq` table to get the rows needed. This part here:

```
SELECT sequences FROM 
(SELECT (LENGTH(val2)-LENGTH(REPLACE(val2,',','')))+1 AS valLen FROM
(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(val),'[',''),']','') AS val2 FROM 
       (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(j.data,'$.options'),'$[*].labelKey') AS val
      FROM d_json j) v1 
    ) v2 ) v3 JOIN number_seq t ON sequences <= valLen
```

Here's an updated fiddle for reference https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ace8babce8d7bbb97f7e016a754e93a9

Comment: Thank you , however "Json_table" is for mysql 8+ but i am using version  5.7.33 :( , Is there another solution that works with older version

Comment: Thank you @FaNo_FN it helped, but its hard coded to 5 result. Any idea how sequence can be generated dynamically

Comment: That's the limitation on older MySQL. If you're using a version that supports window function like `WITH RECURSIVE`, be it MySQL or MariaDB, it will be very easy to create the sequence. The only option that I can think of is generating a range of numbering sequence and uses a `LENGTH()` function to get the total values and add that in the `WHERE` filter... but that would make the query longer and it's still a hardcoding method. I'll put an update in my answer for you to try.

Comment: Thanks for the detail . looking forward for coming update

Comment: I already updated the answer @IjazAhmed . I didn't include the numbering row sequence query in the update though but you can find an example in the updated fiddle link.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FaNo_FN